# Can median be expressed using linear combinations and max?

Tags: optimization, median, tropical-geometry

The median of two numbers is their mean, $(a+b)/2$, the median of three numbers is their sum less their maximum and minimum, i.e.

$$Median(a,b,c) =  a + b + c - \max(a,\max(b,c)) - \min(a,\min(b,c)) $$
$$ = a + b + c - \max(a,\max(b,c)) + \max(-a,\max(-b,-c)) $$

and the median of 4 numbers proceeds similarly (since it's the mean of the center two,

$$Median(a,b,c,d) =  \frac{a + b + c + d - \max(\max(a,b),\max(c,d)) - \min(\min(a,b),\min(c,d))}{2} $$
$$ = \frac{a + b + c + d - \max(\max(a,b),\max(c,d)) + \max(\max(-a,-b),\max(-c,-d))}{2} $$

But is there any similar expression for 5 elements? If there are, bonus points for proof of minimality of your expression (by whatever metric you care), or generalizations to larger sets of elements, of course!

(Background, if anyone is curious: This question was prompted by some machine learning code, where max/min are standard reduction functions, but medians are not; and when considering an ensemble of 5 models -- a pretty common number -- this would be useful. But this question seemed mathematically interesting on its own.)

Comment: For 5 elements why couldn't you take the Max and Min elements away and then calculate the median of the remaining 3? This idea could easily be generalized to any number of elements.

Comment: The question is how to "take them away", which I don't see a straightforward way to accomplish with an expression as in the above. While you're right that for a computer algorithm this would be a fine solution, it's not a solution that would run very well (at least, not without being very clever) on a GPU.

Comment: @AlexMeiburg I am no expert on GPU programming, but this seems like an ideal use case for a small sorting network approach, where you run a fixed number of $(x, y) \leftarrow (min(x, y), max(x, y))$ steps on various pairs of array indices which is guaranteed to sort the array, then take the middle element.

Comment: @Joppy that's also a good solution. It seems that for $n=5$ this can be done with a sorting network with 6 comparisons, or equivalently 11 applications of max/min (2 for each comparison, but only needing one result from the latter). This is probably close to optimal for a GPU! I am separately curious about expressions though, as the sorting network would lead to a very large expression tree (due to expression reuse).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a silly way of extracting the $k$th-largest element from $n$ numbers using only max and min. Let $[n]$ denote the set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, then the $k$-th largest element of $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ is
$$ \min_{\substack{I \subseteq [n] \\ |I| = n - k + 1}} \max_{i \in I} a_i$$

In the example with $5$ elements, to find the largest element, the formula gives
$$\min(\max(a, b, c, d, e)) = \max(a, b, c, d, e)$$
while to find the second largest element, the formula gives
$$\min(\max(b, c, d, e), \max(a, c, d, e), \max(a, b, d, e), \max(a, b, c, e), \max(a, b, c, d))$$
The reason this works is that one of the five must be the maximum, and will appear in all but one $\max(\cdots)$ expression: the $\min$ operation finds this expression. You can then plug this into similar expressions that you had above.

I make no claims as to the minimality of this formula, and it would be pretty outrageous to use this for large sets. But for $n=5$ it might hit the spot.

Comment: This is a good answer! A couple things though. When selecting an element below the median, it might be easier to flip max/min: choosing the second smallest element would be a min-of-10-maxes-of-2 as you wrote it, but by symmetry of course could be max-of-5-mins-of-4. For $n=5$, I can see selecting the median directly with your formula -- a min of 10 maxes, with each max of 3 things. But I can also use the form above to to select the least, second-to-least, greatest, and second-greatest elements, and subtract that from the sum. That's of course more complicated here, but not by much..! Thanks!

Comment: @Joppy This is the *most* elegant way I have ever seen to represent $k$-th largest number of a set. But I am not sure how you came with this formulation (even though you call it "silly"), could you provide more information about this?

Answer (score 0):

The median-of-5 can be calculated from two chained median-of-3s:

med(a, b, c, d, e) = med(med(max(a, e), min(b, d), c), min(a, e), max(b, d))

"Proof": Try to get a large result with any two large inputs and three small inputs. Not possible.