# Is any $k$-th largest element of $\{\mathbf{w}_1^T\mathbf{x},\cdots,\mathbf{w}_n^T\mathbf{x}\}$ piecewise linear?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, maxima-minima

## Problem

This question is motivated by this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2394092/can-median-be-expressed-using-linear-combinations-and-max), which represents $k$-th largest element of a set $\{a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n\}$ (elegantly) as
$$
\min _ { I \subseteq [ n ] \atop \vert I\vert = n - k + 1 } \max _ { i \in I } a _ { i }
$$
Reflecting that one condition (see page3 of [slide](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/ee236a/lectures/pwl.pdf)) for convex piecewise linear function is that it could be represented as 
$$
f ( x ) = \max _ { i = 1 , \ldots , m } \left( a _ { i } ^ { T } x + b _ { i } \right)
$$
I am now wondering if the function of finding $k$-th largest element of set $\{\mathbf{w}_1^T\mathbf{x}.\mathbf{w}_2^T\mathbf{x}.\cdots,\mathbf{w}_n^T\mathbf{x}\}$ is still piecewise linear. For example, median function $f(\mathbf{x})=\text{median}(\mathbf{w}_1^T\mathbf{x}.\mathbf{w}_2^T\mathbf{x},\mathbf{w}_3^T\mathbf{x})$.

Comment: No, it's not, as LinAlg points out in his answer—but in fact, the _sum_ of the $k$ largest elements is convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is piecewise linear, but not convex, assuming that $n$ is finite. You can prove this by induction on $k$. Let us define a few sets to show the first induction steps:
$$S =\{a_i \}$$
$$T =\{a_i + a_j : i < j \}$$
$$U =\{a_i + a_j + a_k : i < j < k  \}$$
Let $a^{(1)} = \max S$ denote the largest element in the set, which is piecewise linear.
The second largest element is $a^{(2)} = \max T - a^{(1)}$, which is the difference of two convex piecewise functions, which is piecewise linear. The third largest element is $a^{(3)} = \max U - a^{(2)}$, etc.